# Access Ganache Accounts via web3

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

How do I create an account variable in web3 with a private network? Right now I am on ganache port:7545

I have this variable written in my code:

```
    var account1 = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

And when I log it, it returns only the variable which is currently selected in my meta mask.

So if I am on Account 1 in meta mask then this^ var logs the address Account 1 and if I am on Account 2 the same var will log the Account 2 address.

So how can I make a var which can access an imported ganache meta mask account which I do not currently have selected?

i.e I have Account1 selected in my meta mask and I want

```
  var account2 = web3.eth.accounts[1]
```

to grab Account2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MetaMask doesn't support this. It will always return an array of size 1 when you use web3.eth.getAccounts(). If you're using Ganache, you can just connect directly to that (as opposed to changing the MetaMask provider to localhost).